# Tensorflow/Python: Function tuple returning copies of first element

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to return 7 values from a function and later print those values.
But when I print them out, I always get seven copies of the first value.

I can't seem to understand what I'm doing wrong though.

What the code is doing is comparing a tensor(array) of `n` elements, and checking the percentage of elements which are under certain thresholds.

```
def accuracy():
  n=7850
  m = 100.0
  difference = tf.abs(tf.subtract(prediction,(labels_tf)))
  one = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[1]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  one = tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  two = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[2]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  two = tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  three =tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[3]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  three =tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  four=  tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[4]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  four= tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  five= tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[5]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  five= tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  ten = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[10]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  ten = tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)

  fifteen =tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(tf.less(difference,[15]),dtype=tf.int32 ))
  fifteen = tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)



  return (one, two, three, four, five, ten, fifteen)

a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a10,a15 = accuracy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `one` into each set of operations on the second line i.e.

```
fifteen = tf.multiply(tf.divide(tf.cast(one,dtype=tf.float32),n ),m)
                                        ^^
```

Comment: uggh. I deserve a bullet for this. Thx!